# Styling input's value CSS

Tags: html, css

So I'm making a contact form and I want to style what a person types into an input. I would like to change the font-family and font-size of it.

```
<input type="text" class="name" placeholder="Your Name"></input>
```

This is what I have as CSS, but I wat to change the value (what someone is typing) as well...

```
.name::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

Comment: I think you have a typo. Remove the second colon (:) after `.name`

Comment: the two colons are fine but a space should be inbetween i think, like this  #form ::-webkit-input-placeholder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you would style the user input. I changed the color to red.

```css
.name:-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.name {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="name" placeholder="Your Name"></input>
```

Answer (score 3):

Placeholder is the text that is already entered as a template e.g "Enter name here".

To style the placeholder text simply use

```
input { 
    font-family:Roboto;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

also your class name is `name` and in your css you have `naam`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more full styling of different form elements including `input`. You can add or remove and play with the values as you want to make it look the way you want.

```
input:not([type]),
input[type=text],
input[type=email],
input[type=search],
input[type=password],
input[type=date],
input[type=datetime-local],
input[type=tel],
input[type=time],
input[type=file],
input[type=url],
input[type=number] {
    transition: color .1s ease,border-color .1s ease;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    line-height: 1.2142em;
    padding: .67861429em 1em;
    font-size: 1em;
    background: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid rgba(34,36,38,.15);
    border-radius: .28571429rem;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 transparent inset;

    ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        color: rgba(191, 191, 191, 0.87);
    }

    ::-moz-placeholder {
        color: rgba(191, 191, 191, 0.87);
    }

    :-ms-input-placeholder {
        color: rgba(191, 191, 191, 0.87);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the * selector like so:

```
    #formID * {
       color: white;
       font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;
       font-size: 25px;
    }
```